# Zoom region that contains points on a map in R

Tags: r, rgdal

The code below generates a map together with points that refer to the coordinates of some houses, but note that it is not possible to see the location of these houses very well. So, is there any way to improve this graph, making it possible, for example, to zoom the map closer to the region of the points?

**Generate map**

```
library(rgdal)
        
temp <- tempfile()
temp2 <- tempfile()
        download.file("https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip",temp)

      
unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)
shp <- readOGR(temp2)
shp_subset <- shp[shp$NM_MUNICIP == "CASTRO",]
plot(shp_subset)
```

**Generate Points**

```
Points_properties<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-24.781624, -24.775017, -24.769196, 
    -24.761741, -24.752019, -24.748008, -24.737312, -24.744718, -24.751996, 
    -24.724589, -24.8004, -24.796899, -24.795041, -24.780501, -24.763376, 
    -24.801715, -24.728005, -24.737845, -24.743485, -24.742601, -24.766422, 
    -24.767525, -24.775631, -24.792703, -24.790994, -24.787275, -24.795902, 
    -24.785587, -24.787558, -24.799524), Longitude = c(-49.937369, 
    -49.950576, -49.927608, -49.92762, -49.920608, -49.927707, -49.922095, 
    -49.915438, -49.910843, -49.899478, -49.901775, -49.89364, -49.925657, 
    -49.893193, -49.94081, -49.911967, -49.893358, -49.903904, -49.906435, 
    -49.927951, -49.939603, -49.941541, -49.94455, -49.929797, -49.92141, 
    -49.915141, -49.91042, -49.904772, -49.894034, -49.86651)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl","data.frame"))

points(x = Points_properties$Longitude, y= Points_properties$Latitude, col = "black",pch = 16,cex=1)
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Does ibge perhaps have cadastral data? The points, relative to the boundary of Castro, are going to plot like that. Cadastral would be the polys that each house point is presumably the centroid of. Ultimately, it would depend either on taxes or city planning, but you're likely looking for a cadastrar layer, and ibge has tons of data...and if found, for Castro, point in polygon.[ibge](https://www.ibge.gov.br/en/geosciences/territorial-organization/territorial-meshes/2998-np-mesh-of-enumeration-areas/28114-malhas-de-setores-censitarios-divisoes-intramunicipais-2.html?edicao=28416&t=o-que-e)

Comment: Well, the spatial you'd want as cadastral, won't be at IBGE as that is outside its mandate [see Technical, 5th paragraph from bottom](https://www.ibge.gov.br/en/geosciences/maps/municipal-maps/31483-colecao-de-mapas-municipais-2.html?edicao=31485&t=notas-tecnicas), but perhaps at the municipal/city planning level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use `ggplot` and `sf` package like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = shp_subset, aes()) +
  geom_point(data = Points_properties, 
             aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude))+
 coord_sf(xlim = c(min(Points_properties$Longitude)-0.1,
                    max(Points_properties$Longitude)+0.1),
          ylim = c(min(Points_properties$Latitude)-0.1,
                   max(Points_properties$Latitude)+0.1),
           expand = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Lucca, that's exactly what I wanted. However, I would like to know if it is possible to zoom in a little more and also, I would like to take this information of lat and long from the graph.